# SwiftUI Keyboardshortcut doesn't work when used on a list item

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a sidebar that contains a list of items. Each item has a right click contextMenu with keyboard shortcuts. However the keyboard shortcuts won't trigger.

Here is a gist with a full example: https://gist.github.com/StefKors/42053f7fb9e424533ac41b627ca5fe7d

[image: picture of rightclick menu in sidebar list]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let data: [Item] = [
        Item(label:"one"),
        Item(label:"two"),
        Item(label:"three"),
        Item(label:"four"),
        Item(label:"five")
    ]

    @State private var selected: Item?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selected) {
                ForEach(data, id: \.id) { item in
                    Text(item.label)
                        .contextMenu {
                            Button("Copy label") {
                                let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
                                pasteboard.clearContents()
                                pasteboard.setString(item.label, forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.string)
                            }
                            .keyboardShortcut("c")
                        }
                        .tag(item)
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            if let selected {
                DestinationView(item: selected)
            } else {
                PlaceholderView()
            }

        }
    }
}
```